# Extracting text inside <div> with multiple tags using jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to extract the text inside the given  element

```
<div class="PuzzleDetails-date--1HNzj"><span>Sunday </span>"February 17, 2019"</div>
```

For this purpose, I use the code given below:

```
Elements dates = document.select("div.PuzzleDetails-date--1HNzj");
for (Element date : dates) {
    System.out.println("Date: " + date.text());
}
```

However, I see no output. I want to see the output as this:

Date: Sunday February 17, 2019

Comment: Try typing this on select method: **.PuzzleDetails-date--1HNzj** Instead of putting _div_ in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`div[class='PuzzleDetails-date--1HNzj']`

```
String s ="<div class=\"PuzzleDetails-date--1HNzj\"><span>Sunday </span>\"February 17, 2019\"</div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(s);

Elements dates = doc.select("div[class='PuzzleDetails-date--1HNzj']");
System.out.println(dates.text());
```

Output:

```
Sunday "February 17, 2019"
```